# Is there a way to speed up my curl requests

Tags: php, curl

I am sending basic cUrl request to an API. When I print `curl_getinfo($ch);` I have noticed that my request took 39.873 sec (total_time) , but connection time was only 0.031 sec (connect_time).

Here is the output of `curl_getinfo()`

```
    [url] => https://api.example.de/Search
    [content_type] => application/json; charset=utf-8
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 427
    [request_size] => 295
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 39.873
    [namelookup_time] => 0.015
    [connect_time] => 0.031
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.109
    [size_upload] => 110
    [size_download] => 1652971
    [speed_download] => 41455
    [speed_upload] => 2
    [download_content_length] => 1652971
    [upload_content_length] => 110
    [starttransfer_time] => 39.359
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )
```

My question is am I in some kind of queue because I am sending request to an API and is there a way to speed this up.

Comment: No, not unless you're also the one creating/maintaining the API.

Comment: _"am I in some kind of queue"_ - From your end, not likely unless you've added some queue yourself. We have no idea about the API you're calling though. If the API takes that long to return the response, there's nothing you can do about it in the client. You would need to check the code in the API.

Comment: @Daan I wonder why the same request took 40 seconds in php and 20 if i run curl shell command